# how can I validate whether values entered in a new form is reflected correctly in edit form

Tags: selenium

I am trying to automate a website which is mainly dealing with Forms. I have entered values in new form and I need to validate whether it is reflected back correctly in edit form. 
In New form I have tried like :

```
 WebElement FN = driver.findElement(By.id("ctl00_ctl41_g_1fc852c8_32cb_4220_80ee_2af21b671f9e_ff21_ctl00_ctl00_TextField"));
 FN.click();
 FN.sendKeys("abc");
```

In the edit form code:

```
 if(FN.getAttribute("value").equals("abc"))
    System.out.println("First Name is matching with new form");
 else                                                        
    System.out.println("First Name is not matching with new form");
```

and I am getting error like

```
 Exception in thread "main" org.openqa.selenium.StaleElementReferenceException: stale element reference: element is not attached to the page document(Session info: chrome=57.0.2987.110)
```

Thanks in advance .

Comment: Did you read the [documentation](http://docs.seleniumhq.org/exceptions/stale_element_reference.jsp)?

Answer (score 1):

You need to reinitialize the **FN** Webelement once you are at edit form, as the previous **FN** Webelement will become stale as soon as you move away from new form. Hence, try following:

```
FN = driver.findElement(By.id("ctl00_ctl41_g_1fc852c8_32cb_4220_80ee_2af21b671f9e_ff21_ctl00_ctl00_TextField"));
if(FN.getAttribute("value").equals("abc"))
    System.out.println("First Name is matching with new form");
else                                                        
    System.out.println("First Name is not matching with new form");
```

Let me know, if you have any further queries.

Answer (score 0):

Possibly, you are having exception at **`FN.sendKeys("abc");`**. When you click on the element before going to edit mode, the element is also changing. That's why you are having that exception.

I suggest, after clicking on the **FN** element have locator for textfield afresh and use `sendkeys()` method on it.

To know about this type of exception this might help you:

http://darrellgrainger.blogspot.com/2012/06/staleelementexception.html